# C# IBM MQ Managed Code SSL handshake does not match

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

This is my first time working with IBM MQ. I have written a simple C# using .Net framewrok 4.8 code block to connect to a local queue with SSL enabled. I am using the IBMMQDotnetClient version 9.3.0 package.

```
using System;
using IBM.WMQ;
using System.Collections;

namespace MqClientTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var queueManagerName = "Queue_Manager";
            var hostName = "localhost";
            var channel = "Local_Channel";
            var queueName = "Local_Queue";
            var port = "5588";
            var sslKeyRepository = "*SYSTEM";
            var cipherSpec = "ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384";
            Hashtable prop = new Hashtable();
            prop.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
            prop.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
            prop.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);
            prop.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT);
            prop.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
            prop.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, sslKeyRepository);
            prop.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, "ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384");

            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in prop)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
            }

            try
            {
                var queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, prop);
                
                MQQueue _queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            }
            catch (MQException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error occurred: {0}, {1}", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A System error occurred: {0}, {1}", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I keep encountering this error:

```
The CipherSpec negotiated during the SSL handshake does not match the required CipherSpec for channel 'Local_Channel'.  

There is a mismatch between the CipherSpecs on the local and remote ends of channel 'Local_Channel'. The channel will not run until this mismatch is resolved. The CipherSpec required in the local channel definition is 'ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384'. The name of the CipherSpec  negotiated during the SSL handshake is 'ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384'. A code is displayed if the name of the negotiated CipherSpec cannot be determined.  

Change the channel definitions for 'Local_Channel' so the two ends have matching CipherSpecs and restart the channel. When using the 'ANY' type CipherSpecs ensure that the client CipherSpec value meets the requirements for the 'ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384' CipherSpec set on the  channel 'Local_Channel'. If the client is set to use a minimum protocol ('ANY', '*_OR_HIGHER') CipherSpec, then the channel definition CipherSpec should be set to use the same minimum protocol CipherSpec, or a stronger, matching CipherSpec, to prevent the  TLS handshake from using a higher protocol than is allowed by the channel definition CipherSpec. If the certificate in use by one end of the channel is a Global Server Certificate, then the negotiated CipherSpec may not match that specified on  either end of the channel. This is because the SSL protocol allows a Global Server Certificate to automatically negotiate a higher level of encryption. In these cases specify a CipherSpec which meets the requirements of the Global Server  Certificate.
```

I am not sure why it says the cipher spec negotiated during the SSL handshake is 'ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384' as you can see in my code, I have already hardcoded to "ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384".

Is there somwhere in windows server 2019 that I need to tweak to get this right? I have also tried to this https://community.ibm.com/community/user/communities/community-home/librarydocuments/viewdocument?DocumentKey=a3eeada6-9b61-4ec8-abe6-5bc61fdbaebc

[image: Channel SSL Properties Settings]

Any pointers to resolve this will be much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Colin

UPDATED:
I finally used the unmanaged MQ Client to connect to the local Queue Manager with SSL (amqmdnet.dll)

```
using System.Collections;
using IBM.WMQ;
using System;

namespace MqClientUnmanaged
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var queueManagerName = "Local_Queue_Manager";
            var hostName = "localhost";
            var channel = "Local_Channel";
            var queueName = "Local_Queue";
            var port = "5588";
            var sslKeyRepository = @"C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\server";
            var cipherSpec = "ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384";
            var certLabel = "ibmmqserver";

            Hashtable prop = new Hashtable();
            prop.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
            prop.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
            prop.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);
            prop.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT);
            //prop.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
            prop.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
            prop.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, sslKeyRepository);
            prop.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, cipherSpec);
            prop.Add(MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY, certLabel);

            //prop.Add("CertificateLabel", certLabel);

            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in prop)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
            }

            try
            {
                
                var queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, prop);

                MQQueue _queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");

                MQMessage retrievedMessage = new MQMessage();
                MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();

                _queue.Get(retrievedMessage, gmo);                
                Console.WriteLine("The message is: {0}", retrievedMessage.ReadString(retrievedMessage.MessageLength));
                Console.WriteLine(new string('*', 100));

            }
            catch (MQException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An IBM MQ error occurred: {0}, {1}", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A System error occurred: {0}, {1}", ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you show us what the SVRCONN channel definition has for its SSLCIPH value? We are only seeing one side of the setup in your description.

Comment: Hi, updated the Channel SSL properties settings image.

Comment: It says "The CipherSpec required in the local channel definition is 'ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384'. " But The name of the CipherSpec negotiated during the SSL handshake is 'ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384'. ". My question is, why is the C# program passing "ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" while I have clearly hard-coded the cipher spec as "ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384" in my code sample above.

Comment: This is how managed .net works.   The cipher you specify on the client is used only as a hint at which tls version to use, see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=client-cipherspec-support-managed-net.  This also talks about about it: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/windows-net-managed-client-using-ssl-tls-unable-connect-mq-queue-manager-using-cipher-eg-tlsrsawithaes128cbcsha256

Comment: If the queue manager is at 9.2 LTS or later you can specify a cipher like ANY_TLS12_OR_HIGHER on the channel to accept what it negotiates to.   You can edit the windows machine policy but this is global for the machine.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc. Now I run into "During handshake, the remote partner sent no certificate.  

The conversation cannot begin because a certificate has not been supplied by the remote partner. &P The channel name is 'Local_Channel'. &P The remote host is 'MQ-Client-Dev (127.0.0.1)'. &P If this error message is written on the receiving side of the channel, then the channel  attributes 'SSLCAUTH' caused the check to be made.  

Look at the key repository on the remote side of this channel, and make sure the appropriate certificates are present, with correct labels."

Comment: I have imported the client and server certificates to both Personal-Certificates and Trusted Root Certification Authorities-Certificates stores.

Comment: What is the friendly name of the personal cert?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248241/discussion-between-colin-chin-and-joshmc).

Comment: I see you got it working with unmanaged,  but what was the cert friendly name in the windows key store for managed mode? There is a bug where you must pass the value to MQ in all lower case even if the friendly name is all UPPER CASE or MiXeD CaSe.

Comment: @JoshMc my managed client always has this error MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE although I use the same parameters, with "prop.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);"

Comment: What did the QMgr show?

Comment: Maybe you have proxy turned on.  See : https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-disable-use-proxy-server-when-using-controller

Comment: @jdweng That document had nothing to do with ibm mq. It is related to IBM Cognos Controller.